# Is there a way to append a Gtk::TreeView - Gtk::ListStore with multithreaded functions?

Tags: c++, gtk, gtk3, gtkmm, gtkmm3

I have a function that appends some rows to a Gtk::TreeView, it's based on the one in the [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-treeview-examples.html.en#liststore-example):

```
Gtk::TreeModel::Row row;

for(const auto& i : some_vector)
{
    row = *(reference_to_list_store->append());
    row[my_column_record.some_value] = i;
}
```

The function in my codebase is similar to this one but it has more cells to fill and the vector can be very large in some cases, in the worst scenario this function takes 12~14s to run and makes a single core go 100%. So i tried to implement this function using more threads:

```
std::mutex mtx;

// That is need to avoid std::future's destructor from blocking the execution.
std::vector<std::future<void>> res;

for(const auto& i : some_vector)
{
    res.emplace_back(std::async(std::launch::async, [&](){
        Gtk::TreeModel::Row row;
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mtx);
            row = *(reference_to_list_store->append());
        }
        row[my_column_record.some_value] = i;
    })); 
}
```

To me this function looks fine, but sometimes, when the array is big and so this function creates a lot of threads, the program may crash. I think that the problem is that I'm trying to append a non blocked resource, but i have no idea on how to fix that.

Comment: How many rows and how many columns does the 14s process have?

Comment: Looks like you try to append to TreeView from other threads, which is UB. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60949269/executing-gtk-functions-from-other-threads)