# C and GTK3 - How to run a thread uninterrupted?

Tags: c, thread-safety, mutex, gtk3

I've been trying to: show 4 random dice faces, 0.4 seconds apart, giving the impression that a dice is rolling. I've put the code to do this in a thread.

But the program crashes after a small number of "rolls". Sometimes it does not even get through the first roll. All sorts of run-time errors are generated.

The last thing I've tried is mutex protection of the thread code. I suspect this is just protecting the code from other threads but my program does not have other threads.

The program is running under Linux and is compiled with: gcc -rdynamic -o test3d1 test3d1.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>

GtkWidget *window;
GtkWidget *vbox;
GtkWidget *butt;
GtkWidget *image;
GdkPixbuf *pixbuf1;
GdkPixbuf *pixbuf2;
GdkPixbuf *pixbuf3;
GdkPixbuf *pixbuf4;
GdkPixbuf *pixbuf5;
GdkPixbuf *pixbuf6;

pthread_t thread;

void *fn_thread ()
{
    gtk_widget_set_sensitive (butt, FALSE);

    int i;
    for(i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
        int j;
        j = rand () % 6 + 1;
        switch (j)
        {
            case 1: gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf (GTK_IMAGE (image), pixbuf1); break;
            case 2: gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf (GTK_IMAGE (image), pixbuf2); break;
            case 3: gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf (GTK_IMAGE (image), pixbuf3); break;
            case 4: gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf (GTK_IMAGE (image), pixbuf4); break;
            case 5: gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf (GTK_IMAGE (image), pixbuf5); break;
            default: gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf (GTK_IMAGE (image), pixbuf6);
        }
        usleep (400000);
    }

    gtk_widget_set_sensitive (butt, TRUE);

    return NULL;
}

void startthread ()
{
    pthread_create (&thread, NULL, fn_thread, NULL);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    srand (time(0));

    pixbuf1 = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file ("dice_1_48x48.png", NULL);
    pixbuf2 = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file ("dice_2_48x48.png", NULL);
    pixbuf3 = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file ("dice_3_48x48.png", NULL);
    pixbuf4 = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file ("dice_4_48x48.png", NULL);
    pixbuf5 = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file ("dice_5_48x48.png", NULL);
    pixbuf6 = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file ("dice_6_48x48.png", NULL);

    image = gtk_image_new ();
    gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf (GTK_IMAGE (image), pixbuf1);

    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 150, 100);

    butt = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Roll");
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (butt), "clicked", G_CALLBACK (startthread), NULL);

    vbox = gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL,10);
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (vbox),image,0,0,0);
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (vbox),butt,0,0,0);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), vbox);
    gtk_widget_show_all (window);

    gtk_main ();

    pthread_join (thread, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60949269/executing-gtk-functions-from-other-threads) has everything you need

Comment: By the way, your mutex protects nothing because it is used in 1 thread only. It doesn't prevent different threads from accessing same data

Comment: 1) I updated the question to remove the mutex code. 2) I looked at the "this" link. But it seems to cover time intervals >= 1 second. 3) I made a loop that does nothing but take up time. But the code still crashes. So I'm not sure if usleep is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60949269/executing-gtk-functions-from-other-threads) answer, you should not be calling GTK functions from any other thread than the one in which `gtk_main` is executed.

In fact, in the [event-driven program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) you should not be using additional threads at all unless you need to optimize some heavy computations. What you should do instead is utilize the features of your event-driven framework, in your case GTK, in order to execute all event handling in the main thread.

In your case this means that you should use `g_timeout_add` function to schedule calling your animation function at regular intervals *from the main thread*:

```
gboolean fn_roll_dice (gpointer)
{
    gtk_widget_set_sensitive (butt, FALSE);

    int j = rand () % 6 + 1;
    switch (j)
    {
        case 1: gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf (GTK_IMAGE (image), pixbuf1); break;
        case 2: gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf (GTK_IMAGE (image), pixbuf2); break;
        case 3: gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf (GTK_IMAGE (image), pixbuf3); break;
        case 4: gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf (GTK_IMAGE (image), pixbuf4); break;
        case 5: gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf (GTK_IMAGE (image), pixbuf5); break;
        default: gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf (GTK_IMAGE (image), pixbuf6);
    }

    gtk_widget_set_sensitive (butt, TRUE);

    return TRUE;
}
    
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ...
    g_timeout_add (400, fn_roll_dice, NULL);

    gtk_main ();

    return 0;
}
```